# Simple value bind to select tag

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, binding

Forgive my noobity, I'm not going to ask you to create a software solution for me, but I just want a quick lesson (or a fix on my code) on how to get my knockout.js working.  You see, I'm a complete newbie on JS, and I'm trying to figure something out here:

```
<p>Show the number here: <span data-bind="text: showVal()" id="curr-value"></span>

                <select data-bind="selectedOptions:selectedBlah, options: $root.numberSet, value: currVal, optionsText: 'numName'">
                </select>

            </p>

            <script type="text/javascript">

              function NumbersSViewModel() {
                self.numberSet = [
                  { numName: "Two in Decimal is", currVal: 2 },
                  { numName: "Three in Decimal is", currVal: 3 },
                  { numName: "Four in Decimal is", currVal: 4 },
                ]

                self.selectedBlah = ko.observableArray([]);

                self.showVal = ko.computed(function() {
                    var value = currVal().toString();
                    return value;
                });

              }

              ko.applyBindings(new NumberSViewModel()); </script>
```

So, what I'm trying to do is, if you set the dropdown menu on a value, the text value on the span changes. I'm sure it's possible, I just can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
function NumbersViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numberSet = [
        { numName: "Two in Decimal is", curVal: 2 },
        { numName: "Three in Decimal is", curVal: 3 },
        { numName: "Four in Decimal is", curVal: 4 },
    ];

    self.selectedNumber = ko.observable();
    }

ko.applyBindings(new NumbersViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: numberSet,
                   optionsText: 'numName',
                   optionsValue: 'curVal',
                   value: selectedNumber"></select>

Show the number here:
<span data-bind="text: selectedNumber" id="curr-value"></span>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boevgrmb/1/)

Comment: Oh, THANK YOU good sir. Most godly programmers won't even waste a wink on a simple question like this, but you did.  I shall train my self better so in the future I'll be of some use to humankind.

Comment: It's not that simple question. Knockout `options` binding is quite complex sometimes.